# Php laravel using post method by controller

Tags: php, laravel

am try to send value form from by post method to controller

here is my view,and how can i use post method to send

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Title:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control" value='{{ $words->first()->title }}' type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Meaning:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control" value="{{ $words->first()->meaning }}" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" type="button">
        <span></span>
        <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="reset">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

here is controller method like

```
public function postSaveedit($meaning){


}
```

using route by controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 5.2 you can use request() helper method to solve your problem...
This is how you can do it...

Routes file should look like this (be sure that this route should be of post type)

```
Route::post('/myurl', 'Controllername@postSaveEdit')->name('postSaveEdit');
```

Form file should look like this, also please specify the input field names in the form so that you can grab them in the the controller by their specified names (like - title, meaning - see below code)...

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('postSaveEdit') }}" method="POST" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Title:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <input class="form-control" name="title" value='{{ $words->first()->title }}' type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Meaning:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <input class="form-control" name="meaning" value="{{ $words->first()->meaning }}" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
      <span></span>
      <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="reset">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and controller should be like this...

```
public function postSaveEdit() {
    // The inputs variable contains all your form's inputs in the form of array...
    $inputs = request()->all();
    /* 
        $inputs = array(
            'title' => 'title_value',
            'meaning' => 'meaning_value'
        )
    */
    // Wheareas you can also get them by using 'get' method on request method like this
    $title = request()->get('title');
    $meaning = request()->get('meaning');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on Requests in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#accessing-the-request

You need to pass that to your controller

```
public function postSaveedit(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->input();
    $foo = $input['foo'];
    $bar = $input['bar'];
    $baz = $input['baz'];

}
```

Comment: and if i send 2 or 3 parameter how i handle in method

Comment: @NonBrazilian You can send as many parameters as you want .. they will all be available in Request. updated answer

Comment: ok another question,how can i update my eloquent object
ex.$words = Word::where('title', $var)->get(); to select object

Comment: All your fields will be there in your request but make sure you have those fields in your fillable to save to the database.

Comment: @NonBrazilian To get a single instance of the eloquent model instead of a collection, use `first()`, like this: `Word::where('title', $var)->first()`

Comment: Word::where('title', $var)->first() will update into database ?

Comment: @NonBrazilian To update database: `Word::find($id)->update($request->input())`

Comment: ok now i can keep value from post how to use ->update($request->input())
with my var

Comment: `Word::where('title', $var)->first()->update(['foo' => $request->get('foo')])` where `foo` is a field in the table

Comment: can you live chat with me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110693/discussion-between-non-brazilian-and-angad-dubey).

Comment: @NonBrazilian Please post any questions you have on stack overflow. this helps the community. Someone else might run into the same problem as you and happen to come across this thread and resolve it.

Comment: ok now my controller like 
public function postSaveedit(Request $request) {
  $var1 = $request->input('title'); //name on the form
  $var2 = $request->input('meaning'); //name on the form

  Word::where('title', $var1)->first()->update(['meaning' => $request->get('meaning')]);

 }
but still not work error Trying to get property of non-object (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel5\resources\views\dict\edit.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

here u go

**Form**

you have to add method to your form + names to your inputs

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
    <!-- Add csrf token -->
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Title:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control" value='{{ $words->first()->title }}' type="text" name="input1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Meaning:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control" value="{{ $words->first()->meaning }}" type="text" name="input2">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
        <span></span>
        <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="reset">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**controller**

```
Use Word; // at the top of the class
public function postSaveedit(Request $request) {
$word= new Word; // if you are creating a new record
$word= Word::find(1);// if you are updating a record

$word->title = $request->input('input1');
$word->meaning= $request->input('input2');
$word->save();

return view('home.blade.php');
```

}

**Routes file**

```
Route::get('/myurl', 'Controllername@postSaveedit');
```

:)

Comment: i dont understand return view('test.blade.php')->with('test1', var1)->with('test2', var2); how it update to database

Comment: thats what wil lhapen next , that will just return a view with the inputs, ill edit answer to update database

Comment: now i try 
public function postSaveedit(Request $request) {
  $var1 = $request->input('title'); //name on the form
  $var2 = $request->input('meaning'); //name on the form
  $words = User::where("title", $var1)->update(array("meaning" => $var2));

  return view('dict.watch', compact('words'));
 }
but it TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:

Comment: chech the form again , the answer was edited by angad (add crsf token )

Comment: make sure you edit names in the view to match the controller